# R: Defining functions within a loop

Tags: r, function

Defining multiple functions in a loop:

```
par <- 1:2    #parameters for functions
qF <- list()  #list I will write the functions into

for(i in 1:2){
  qF[[i]] <- function(p){qnorm(p, mean = par[i])}
}
```

My result:

```
>qF
[[1]]
function (p) 
{
qnorm(p, mean = par[i])
}

[[2]]
function (p) 
{
qnorm(p, mean = par[i])
}
```

The functions are the same! What I WANT my result to be:

```
>qF
[[1]]
function (p) 
{
 qnorm(p, mean = par[1])
}

[[2]]
 function (p) 
{
 qnorm(p, mean = par[2])
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I just hope this will not lead to `eval(parse())`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create the functions dynamically you need for the `par[i]` to evaluate each time, otherwise all the `par[i]` will be evaluated when the functions are called, and `i` will be the value at the end of the loop.

```
for(i in 1:2){
    qF[[i]] <- local({
        mu <- par[i]
        function(...) { qnorm(..., mean = mu) }   
    })
}
```

You could also `substitute` the variable into the function body

```
for(i in 1:2){
    qF[[i]] <- eval(substitute(
        function(...) qnorm(..., mean = mu)), list(mu=par[i]))
}
```

And you can see what `mu` is in each function's environment

```
sapply(qF, function(f) mget("mu", environment(f)))
# $mu
# [1] 1
# 
# $mu
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks this is exacly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
library(functional)

funcs = lapply(1:2, function(u) Curry(qnorm, mean=u)) 

funcs[[1]](0.77)
#[1] 1.738847

funcs[[2]](0.77)
#[1] 2.738847
```

Or if you do not appreciate spicy meals:

```
funcs = lapply(1:2, function(u) function(...) qnorm(..., mean=u))
```

Comment: The unCurried version only works with R 3.2 or above, as that one fixed a wart with lapply and lazy evaluation.

Comment: no problem ;) But just one advice: playing with eval, get and explicit for loop is clearly not the way to code/learn R! It's preferable to have shorter and more high level coding approach!