# R: Iteratively Defining functions inside functions

Tags: r, function, loops, function-definition

Given a list of functions

```
functions <- list(f1,f2)
```

I want to iteratively redefine all functions in this list so that I get

```
newFunctions <- list(function(...){f1(...) + 1},function(...){f2(...) + 1})
```

I tried to achieve this with

```
newFunctions <- lapply(functions, function(i){
  return(function(...){
    return(i(...) + 1)
    }
}
```

but this hardcodes `i` into the functions instead of the function that the iterator points to.

I have found [R: Defining functions within a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556088/r-defining-functions-within-a-loop), where the solution is to evaluate the iterator before defining the function. However, I can't evaluate `i`, since I'm iterating over functions

Is there any way to implement this in R?

Comment: I have already problems with the start of your question. What you show there is not a list of functions. It's a list of the return values of these functions.

Comment: I used `f1(a,b)` to outline the definition of `f1`. The actual R code is `list(f1,f2,f3)`

Comment: Maybe something like `functions <- list(sin, cos, tan); lapply(functions, function(x) function(...) x(...) + 1)`?

Comment: @Roland your suggestion hardcodes `x` into the function instead of `sin cos tan`

Comment: @mtoller The name `x` is hardcoded but the results of `newFunctions[[1]](x)` and of `1 + sin(x)` are `identical`.

Comment: My code creates closures. `x = sin` is defined in the function's associated environment. This is the only way I see with an arbitrary list of functions as input. If you had a list of closures or a list of expressions, alternatives would be possible.

Comment: Interesting. This means that my original suggestion works as well. But why does `print(newFunctions)` not reflect that `i` is replaced with the respective function?

Comment: @Roland if you maybe combine your comments to an answer, then I will mark that answer as accepted

Comment: See what `e <- environment(newFunctions[[1]]); e$i` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's fix the syntax error by getting rid of the explicit `return` calls:

```
newFunctions <- lapply(functions, function(x) function(...) x(...) + 1)
```

An example of usage:

```
functions <- list(sin, cos, tan)
newFunctions <- lapply(functions, function(x) function(...) x(...) + 1)
identical(
  newFunctions[[1]](1), 
  sin(1) + 1
)
#[1] TRUE
```

The code creates closures. `x` is taken from the associated environment:

```
newFunctions[[1]]
#function(...) x(...) + 1
#<environment: 0x000000001a812138>
environment(newFunctions[[1]])$x
#function (x)  .Primitive("sin")
```